# How to connect RStudio using Shiny to Microsoft 365

Tags: r, shiny, office365

I have a lot of googlesheets that i write in and out from using R. We are merging our sheets into Office online(365). 
How can i connect to the online microsoft services (365) from R, especially Excel. 
I currently use library(googlesheets) to connect via R.
I will also in instances write some of the current googlesheet data out to the Shiny server using R. I'm looking for some advice and can this be done. 
Thanks

Comment: You can mount Office365 as an ODBC data source as described in [this](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/office365-odbc-r.rst) guide although I've no direct experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AzureGraph R package by Microsoft ([documentation](https://github.com/Azure/AzureGraph)) to get a token via your active directory. Then use the Graph API ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0)) with the call_graph_url function from AzureGraph.

I had issues downloading via the API call, so I used the httr GET function and readxl package once I was able to find the graph download URL:

```
GET(item[["@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl"]], write_disk(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")))
```

`df <- read_excel(tf)`

Answer (score 0):

Per 2022, there is a new (official) package in play that will suit your needs:

https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft365R